# 64 bit for Dell Poweredge 2950?

Tags: software-installation

I have a used Dell Poweredge 2950. It has Windows Server 2003 x86 with 4 gigs of RAM. I want to get more RAM and run a 64 bit OS. Is there a 64 bit Ubuntu Server operating system for Dell Poweredge 2950 Servers?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is affirmatively  yes.  Ubuntu runs pretty well from that machine. I should know, I'm running on it as we speak.